# How to run jmeter test through remote servers via jenkins

Tags: jmeter, jenkins-pipeline

I am having a linux machine (say m1) [an openStack machine] to run my jmeter test. 
My typical process was to put latest jmx file on this machine and trigger below command: 
nohup /path/to/jmeter/bin/jmeter -n -t /path/to/script/test.jmx -l /path/to/resultsFolder/results.jtl

Now, I want to trigger same test via jenkins job which should actually do the same activity as above.

I perform two activities (one is  to manually trigger jmeter-server on m1 and other to run jenkins job to run test via m1)

1. To start jmeter server
   Ran following command manually on m1 ( SERVER_PORT=1099 nohup /path/to/jmeter/bin/jmeter-server)
2. Jenkins Job

I have created a jenkins pipeline job:
Stage1: checks out jmeter in jenkins master
stage2: checks out latest script in jenkins master
stage3: Runs jmeter remote test -
         command used : 
sh '''
chmod u+x jmeter/bin/jmeter.sh 
jmeter/bin/jmeter.sh -n -t path/where/jenkins/checked/latest/test/test.jmx -R 10.X.X.X -l results.jtl'''

- Stage1 and stage2 runs perfectly.
- Stage3: console output shows as below

  - jmeter/bin/jmeter.sh -n -t jmeter/bin/jmeter.sh -n -t path/where/jenkins/checked/latest/test/test.jmx -R 10.X.X.X -l results.jtl
- Creating summariser
- Created the tree successfully using path/where/jenkins/checked/latest/test/test.jmx
- Configuring remote engine: 10.X.X.X
- Starting remote engines
- Starting the test @ Tue Aug 14 10:41:46 CEST 2018 (1534236106818)
- Remote engines have been started
- Waiting for possible shutdown message on port 4445

And it keep showing processing ......... unless I trigger manual shutdown.

So, I'm looking for two things

- a mechanism to start jmeter-server on slave nodes via jenkins job itself
- Running test via remote machines (which can go locations within load machine and trigger test from there itslef)

. Any ideas appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can launch jmeter server on remote slaves in at least 2 ways:

1. From Jenkins using [Jenkins SSH Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin)
2. From JMeter itself using [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) or [SSH Command plugin](https://github.com/yciabaud/jmeter-ssh-sampler#ssh-command) (in this case you will have 2 scripts, one which will set everything up and another will be the main test in distributed mode.

Comment: Thanks For information. I am able to start jmeter server on remote machine. But still I am seeing same issue. If you see error pasted in actual post, earlier also remote engines were configured and then started successfully, and message says, even test is started and it is waiting for possible shutdown message on port 4445.   So, it looks, jenkins machine was able to communicate already with remote machine, but actual test was not started.